# Change Header Minicart container effect from dropdown to slide(right to left) in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs

After added any product to cart we can see that item in minicart header. So when we click on minicart then it's show product with dropdown effect. I want to change this dropdown effect to slider from right to left.

I have attached image and effect showing in image is dropdown.

[image]

And one more thing is this minicart dropdown effect work using Knockout.js I have found  .js file that is responsible for dropdown effect but now I want to change this effect to slide from right to left.

Below is part of **minicart.phtml** file.

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
         data-role="dropdownDialog"
         data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
            "triggerTarget":".showcart",
            "timeout": "2000",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",
            "buttons":[]}}'>
        <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
    </div>
```

In above code if we show I'm sure  **`data-role="dropdownDialog"`** and **`data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{}}`** coming from **knockout.Js**.

So I go to **app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart.js** file and I found below code.

```
miniCart.on('dropdowndialogopen', function () {
    initSidebar();
});

closeSidebar: function () {
        var minicart = $('[data-block="minicart"]');
        minicart.on('click', '[data-action="close"]', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('close');
        });

        return true;
    }
```

SO I thought if I'll change **`dropdownDialog`** to **`SlideRight/SlideLeft`** then my issue will solve but after done this minicart dropdown stop working.

So can anyone help me to change minicart **dropdown effect** to **sliderRight to Left**? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add jQuery UI options "show" to do animate effect:

```
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
    <div class="block block-minicart empty"
         data-role="dropdownDialog"
         data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
            "triggerTarget":".showcart",
            "timeout": "2000",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",

            "show":{"effect":"slide", "duration":800},

            "buttons":[]}}'>
        <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: The same properties can be used for closing but the key is named "hide". Example: "hide":{"effect":"slide", "duration":800}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly the solution I found is standard or not but I would like to share my code which worked fine. I override **minicart.phtml** file from **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml** to my theme and added below code at thee end of file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     require(['jquery'], function($){ 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("[data-block='minicart']").on("dropdowndialogopen", (e) => {
                $(".block-minicart").hide();
                $(".block-minicart").slideDown("slow");                 
            });
            $("[data-block='minicart']").on("dropdowndialogclose", (e) => {
               $(".mage-dropdown-dialog").show();
               $('.block-minicart').slideUp("slow");
            });
        });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off let me clear up somethings for you.

- `dropdowndialogopen` is an event
- `data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{}}` passes {...} back to a matching javascript component by config. Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html
- `data-role="dropdownDialog"` is $(elem).data('role') -- a way to retrieve embedded data in html markup. Ref: https://api.jquery.com/data/

There is currently no animation involved when using the dropdown dialogue. So the left/right behavior is something you would have to implement yourself. You can override or extend magentos dialogue wrapper here: `<mage_root>/lib/web/mage/dropdown.js`

Hope this gives you a good starting point. :)